# Swift casting causes the app to crash

Tags: swift, casting, crash

I've been having this odd error in a recent swift program of mine. It involves random occurrences, and to simulate this I assign an event 'odds,' then generate two random numbers (using these odds), and if the numbers are the same then the action occurs. But the program crashes, inexplicably, in the generation part. The only explanation I can think of is the overabundance of casting required, but I'm not sure why it only crashes once in a while. I'd appreciate any insight as to why the casting crashes and any suggestions for what to do to avoid such excessive casting.

 My image shows the code and the error, and the code below is a generalization of my code.
[Crash Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUL4V.png)

```
let rand = [Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(someInt))), Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(someInt)))]
if (rand[0] == rand[1]) {
    executeAction()
}
```

Comment: Just for clarification, arc4random_uniform takes UInt32 and returns UInt32. My someInt is a single digit integer.

Comment: This is not crashing for me, what does someInt contain?

Comment: An exponentially growing number, apparently. In certain situations, I doubled the odds (from 3 to 6)... but because the odds were global they retained the increase and kept doubling. I'm guessing the UInt32 maxed out and threw the error. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs because your integer variable `shootOdds`, at some point, takes a negative value (or: less plausible, a value larger than `4,294,967,295`), causing runtime error for cast to unsigned integer, `UInt32(someInt)`. You can avoid this by making sure, prior to the `let rand = ...` row, that `shootOdds >= 0` (or in your code example above, `someInt >= 0`), or that you number is not larger than the upper limit for `UInt32`.

Hence note that the error is not associated with the rand function, but specifically the negative integer cast to unsigned integer.

E.g., try the following example in your playground, to assert you get the same runtime error:

```
let a = -1
let b = UInt32(a)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! As it turns out, the number was too large, not negative. I had some bad code which was exponentially increasing the odds until they were greater than 32 bits.

Comment: Heh I was guessing considering too large but thought negative to be more plausible. I'll edit into the answer to make it exhaustive.

Comment: The playground idea was really good, I should have messed around with that in the first place. Using it, I figure that in 20 to 25 iterations of the doubling the UInt32 would crash. That explains why it would only happen after a while.

Comment: Yeah, playground are really helpful for learning.  Good luck with your swifting, and remember to visit the playground when things don't make sense!

Answer (score 0):

Due to faulty code, my odds were increasing exponentially and eventually too large to be contained in UInt32... and thus the error. Thanks for the help!